# How to change the height and width of switch in kendo UI angular using css?

Tags: css, angular, web, kendo-ui

I am working with `angular` and `Kendo ui`.

**How to change the height and width of switch button in kendo UI angular using css?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply try this:

```
<kendo-switch [(ngModel)]="checked" style="height:50px; width:100px"></kendo-switch>
```

but I think the result is not what you really want.
So, try that as well:

```
<kendo-switch [style.transform]="'scale(0.9, 0.9)'" [(ngModel)]="checked"></kendo-switch>
```

and take a look at [transform-scale](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/scale) to find out more info and modify the dimensions accordingly to achieve the desirable outcome.

Comment: thanks for answer. that code blog works.

<kendo-switch [style.transform]="'scale(0.9, 0.9)'" [(ngModel)]="checked"></kendo-switch>

Comment: I just mentioned scale(0.9, 0.9) as an example. You may want to change the dimensions to achieve a result that fits best your case.

Comment: i know, thank you for details and attention